# How to use custom event from JS into angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to listen on event from js library in angular component. I couldn't find any answer about it on google.

Example:

```
someElement.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp, passiveSupported
                               ? { passive: true } : false);
```

Do I have to convert `someElement` into directive component? Or can I do it in that way that I have reference on that element:

```
@ViewChild("someElement")
public someElement: ElementRef;
```

Comment: You can try using the mouseup event on the element and see what the event gives you:
<div (mouseup)="handleMouseUp($event)">Element</div>

Comment: This is not working, some times that event is running and most of the time not. I used `Renderer2 from @angular/core`